# Flask Jinja2 exception when a variable starts with a digit on render_template_string method

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, render

I need to render a string template that has tags that starts with a number and I get this exception:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'd_printer_name'

```
>>> jinja2.__version__
'2.10.3'
>>> flask.__version__
'1.1.1'
```

*hello.py*:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    render_data = { "3d_printer_name": "A name for printer"}
    rendered = render_template_string("Name: {{ 3d_printer_name}}.", **render_data)

    return rendered
```

I also try putting {% autoescape false %} tag but the problem still is there.

Any help is welcome!

This is the traceback:

```
[2019-11-07 14:11:50,609] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/mgieco/Developments/tmp/flask_render/hello.py", line 8, in hello
    decoration = render_template_string("Name: {{ 3d_printer_name}}.", **decoration_data)
  File "/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 155, in render_template_string
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.from_string(source), context, ctx.app)
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 880, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse
    return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 901, in parse
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 876, in subparse
    self.stream.expect('variable_end')
  File "/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py", line 384, in expect
    self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'd_printer_name'
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Nov/2019 14:11:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: simply use name without number. OR add some char (or `_`) at the beginning.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. It is not possible to change the way the name is received. I thought to rename them before parsing, but if an error is risen, the message from the exception is not clear (bc the name is not the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can't use variables which start with number. And when you use `**render_data` then it convert dictionary to separated variables. It seems it skiped `3` and in error message it shows problem with `d_printer_name`

But you can send it as dictionary (instead of converting to separated variables)

```
render_template_string(..., my_data=render_data)
```

and then you can use it like dictionary

```
"{{ my_data['3d_printer_name'] }}"
```

---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    render_data = {"3d_printer_name": "A name for printer"}
    rendered = render_template_string("Name: {{ my_data['3d_printer_name'] }}.", my_data=render_data)
    return rendered

app.run()
```

Comment: Hi, I think I could use these approach to fix the error. Receive the template, parse it to add "my_data['variable']" and render it.
Of course, any other suggestion is welcome :D
Thanks!